# Fullscreen Cocoa app retina support

Tags: macos, cocoa, fullscreen, retina-display

I'm developing a screenshot application working in fullscreen mode. I have a bug report about issues with MBP Retina, but I have no idea how to test and fix them. It looks like QuartzDebug can change displays to HiDPI mode, but I'm not sure that will do the trick. Can't find any "Retina Emultaion" related topics in Apple docs.

So my question is how can I test app (not just icons, but whole fullscreen application) for being compatible with retina display without buying one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's actually all in the Apple docs, though slightly hard to find: [Testing High Resolution Content](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/HighResolutionOSX/Testing/Testing.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012302-CH6-SW1).

I'll sum it up for you: you should always test on a real device (or go to the Apple Store and put your application on to one of their demo retinas). But as an intermediate step, emulating the retina works too.

Quartz Debug's HiDPI mode works for this, and is a method Apple delineates as one to test with. You can also tint high resolution images using the command (in Terminal)

```
defaults write -g CGContextHighlight2xScaledImages YES
```